# How to represent all ManyToMany fields in djangorestgramework serializer class?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to render ManyToMany fields with there values using django.

Base model

```
class SalesAction(models.Model):
    sales_representative = models.ForeignKey(
        SalesRepresentative, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    doctor = models.ForeignKey(Doctor, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    remark = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    date = models.DateField()
    medicines = models.ManyToManyField(Medicine, through='SalesActionMedicine')

    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.sales_representative} - {self.doctor}'
```

Details model

```
class SalesActionMedicine(models.Model):
    sales_action = models.ForeignKey(SalesAction, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    medicine = models.ForeignKey(Medicine, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    quantity_type = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    quantity = models.PositiveIntegerField()
```

What I want is to represent all medicines related to each object in the `SalesAction` model class.

This is the serializer I built.

```
class SalesActionMedicineSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = SalesActionMedicine
        fields = ('sales_action', 'medicine', 'quantity_type', 'quantity')
```

```
class SalesActionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    medicines = SalesActionMedicineSerializer(many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SalesAction
        fields = ('sales_representative', 'doctor', 'remark', 'date', 'medicines')
```

This code gives my this error:

`Got AttributeError when attempting to get a value for field`sales_action`on serializer`SalesActionMedicineSerializer`. The serializer field might be named incorrectly and not match any attribute or key on the` Medicine`instance. Original exception text was: 'Medicine' object has no attribute 'sales_action'.`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `MedicineSerializer` to get medicines instead of `SalesActionMedicineSerializer`.
You can also get SaleActionMedicine data with reverse.

So, code will be

```
class SalesActionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    medicines = MedicineSerializer(many=True)
    sales_medicines = SalesActionMedicineSerializer(source='salesactionmedicine_set', many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = SalesAction
        fields = ('sales_representative', 'doctor', 'remark', 'date', 
                  'medicines', 'sales_medicines')
```

Comment: But I need to get the fields in the `through` attribute.

Comment: I updated answer for your request